# jQuery draggable item and div scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a horizontal list of items that can be drag to a second div.

that list can be overflow inside his div container so the user have to scroll to see the other items.

my problem on mobile view is when you want to scroll with your fingers to see the other items, you actually start dragging one of the item so you can scroll the div.

[here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/3fevr1ao/3/). please open it on mobile

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="drop_zone"></div>
      <div class="items_container">
        <div class="drag_item">a</div>
        <div class="drag_item">b</div>
        <div class="drag_item">c</div>
        <div class="drag_item">d</div>
        <div class="drag_item">e</div>
        <div class="drag_item">f</div>
      </div>
    </div>



$('.drop_zone').droppable({
     drop: function (event, ui) {
     $(ui.helper).clone(true, true).appendTo($(this));
   }
 });

 $('.drag_item').draggable({
        helper : 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body',
 });
```

for touch events i'm using [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)

any ideas?
[image]

Comment: i updated my question with jsfiddle link

Comment: Tough one, 1) Could make your own scroll buttons that appear for mobile. 2) Make a larger margin around the drag items so the user has more finger space to scroll in the div.

Comment: thanks @Twisty, do you think it can work with long tap and drag for the draggable items?

Comment: @user2587454 I suspect it could. Getting the user to understand this might be more difficult.

Comment: Are you using or have thought about jQuery Mobile? Could help detect swipe versus tap-n-drag

Comment: @Twisty is there a way to do that with touch punch? if i want to trigger the dragging only when you tap and hold?

Comment: @user2587454 Have never used it  so I will have to investigate. I could see it working, where you do not init  theitems as draggable up front. This allows for swipe to occur regularly. Then when tap-hold triggers, it could init the div as draggable at that instance so it can be dragged.